# How would I use button in the following situation in grails?

Tags: grails, button, view, controller

I am returning a map value that contain multiple items. The map is as follows:

```
def myList = []

//Some code to obtain the List

List << ["Id": Id,"Name": Name,"Code": sCode, "RunType": x ]
return [items: List]
```

In my GSP page I am using the following code to print them out in my web page.

```
            <%
            def counter = 0

            for (i in items) {
                counter = counter + 1

                println("<td>" + i + "</td>" + "\n")

                if (counter == 1) {
                    println("</tr><tr>")
                    counter = 0
                }
            }

        %>
```

And the output looks as follows:

```
[Id:i-d0f5, Name:es_test_1b_110.test.com, Code:16, RunType:On Demand]
[Id:i-7890, Name:namc-qc.test.com, Code:16, RunType:On Demand]
[Id:i-ee56, Name:abcdef.test.com, Code:16, RunType:On Demand]
[Id:i-c41e, Name:backup.grails.test.com, Code:80, RunType:On Demand]
```

What I need now is to add a button for each of the values printed (so if 6 servers are printed 6 buttons will show up and if 10 servers are printed 10 buttons will show up)  i will be using the button to pass the Id to start and stop the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails has some powerful built-in GSP tags which come in quite handy here.  For example:

```
<g:each in="${items}" var="i">
  <tr>
    <td>${i.Id}</td>
    <td>${i.Name}</td>
    <td>${i.Code}</td>
    <td>${i.RunType}</td>
    <td><a class="button" href="${createLink(controller: '<controllerName>', action: 'start', id: i.Id)}">Start</a></td>
  </tr>
</g:each>
```

There are, of course, many other ways to approach this, but I hope this is a start.  For more, see these sections in the Grails ref doc: [each](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html), [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html)

Comment: My id, Name, Code and RunType are not getting resolved. Any ideas why?

Comment: +1 @Andrew. Test User: You might see them not resolved in IDE but if you test it or run it you should be able to see the expected result.